# setting multiple apply columns

Tags: pandas, variables, apply

I'm trying to set multiple columns with the apply method from an array (instead of having 3 different lines as the declaration).  I would like to have 3 columns set from the dataframe apply method by different args from an array.

declaring in separate lines works, but not very clean.

```
days=np.array([30,45,60])

def move(row,days):
    return row.X / 100 *  np.sqrt(days/365)

### I am trying to clean this up -- there's got to be a simpler way!!
#df['Move30'] = df.apply(move,args=(days[0], ),axis=1)
#df['Move45'] = df.apply(move,args=(days[1], ),axis=1)
#df['Move60'] = df.apply(move,args=(days[2], ),axis=1)

### This succeeds but not any cleaner

df['Move30'], df['Move45'], df['Move60'] = df.apply(move,args=(days[0], ),axis=1), df.apply(move,args=(days[1], ),axis=1), df.apply(move,args=(days[2], ),axis=1)

### Is there some way to create...?
df['Move30'], df['Move45'], df['Move60'] = df.apply(move,args=([days[0],days[1],days[2]], ),axis=1)
```

Comment: You could do this, sure, but I think it would be much better to vectorize your code. Is this actually your code or is it some other (more complicated function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this as a for loop:

```
for d in days:
    df[f'Move{d}'] = df.apply(move,args=(d, ),axis=1)
```

*In python 2 you'd have to use `'Move' + str(d)` instead of f'Move{d}'.*

However, I suspect you'd be better off vectorizing this...

Comment: Thanks Andy, that's what I was looking for, and it works.  You also showed something for which I've been looking for years, the df[f assignment ability.